# String concatenation using String interpolation

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I've something like below.

```
var amount = "$1,000.99";
var formattedamount = string.Format("{0}{1}{0}", "\"", amount);
```

How can I achieve same using String interpolation?

I tried like below

```
var formattedamount1 = $"\"{amount}\"";
```

Is there any better way of doing this using string interpolation?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Gilead green,  I want wrap in quotes so that amount will not populate in multiple cells in CSV file.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi that what you have in your first example, will not even compile.

Comment: @SeM, it is now. Please check

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi You can check my answer below.

Comment: By performing the last update you make the answers below not relevant. In addition you did not explain then what is the "new" question...

Comment: Now your question is unclear, cause it will print out exact same thing as your first expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

> Is there any better way of doing this using string interpolation

No, this is just string interpolation, you cant make the following any shorter and more readable really

```
var formattedamount1 = $"\"{amount}\"";
```

**Original answer**

[$ - string interpolation (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

> To include a brace, "{" or "}", in the text produced by an
>   interpolated string, use two braces, "{{" or "}}". For more
>   information, see Escaping Braces.

Quotes are just escaped as normal

**Example**

```
string name = "Horace";
int age = 34;

Console.WriteLine($"He asked, \"Is your name {name}?\", but didn't wait for a reply :-{{");
Console.WriteLine($"{name} is {age} year{(age == 1 ? "" : "s")} old.");
```

**Output**

```
He asked, "Is your name Horace?", but didn't wait for a reply :-{
Horace is 34 years old.
```

Comment: @GiladGreen there definitely was some confusion going on there though

Comment: @TheGeneral, what was the confusion.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi `var formattedamount1 = $"{"\""{amount}{"\""}";` this line

Comment: @TheGeneral and this line - _"How can I achieve same using String interpolation?"_

Comment: @SeM whats the point of just fixing the error, when you can learn someone something ;) and also plug the documentation

Comment: @SeM, using string format, I'm using {0} twice ( prefix, suffix), can I achieve same using $ without defining quotes

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi the question is why

Comment: @TheGeneral, correct I just typed using mobile and i don't have C# editor. My intention is same

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi Imho it's more readable to see quotes, than something like `{N}`.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing you can achieve by doing:

```
var formattedamount1 = $"\"{amount}\"";
```

OR

```
var formattedamount1 = $@"""{amount}""";
```

It's basically allowing you to write `string.Format()`, but instead of using one string with "placeholders"(`{0}, {1}, .. {N}`), you are directly writing/using your variable inside `string`.

Please read more about **[String Interpolation (DotNetPerls)](https://www.dotnetperls.com/string-interpolation)**, **[$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)** to fully understand whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give one more option, if you want to make sure you use the same quote at both the start and the end, you could use a separate variable for that:

```
string quote = "\"";
string amount = "$1,000.99";
string formattedAmount = $"{quote}{amount}{quote}";
```

I'm not sure I'd bother with that personally, but it's another option to consider.